# neo4j: how to return nodes' content with node name?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cypher-3.1

I select a path and want to return distinct nodes from that path with labels:

```
match path = ...
unwind(nodes(path)) as node
return distinct node { .*, type: labels(node)}
```

As a result I get

```
[{node={a:1, b:2, type=[t]}}, {node={a:3, b:4 type=[x]}}]
```

i want to get rid of the `node` text and receive:

```
[{a:1, b:2, type=[t]}, {a:3, b:4 type=[x]}]
```

how can i achieve that?

neo4j version 3.3.1: 
`docker run --rm -p 7474:7474 --env=NEO4J_AUTH=none neo4j:3.3.1`

Comment: Running your query here returns the expected result (without `node` text). Which version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: @BrunoPeres 3.3.1 - updated the question

Comment: I'm ran your query in Neo4j 3.3.0 and worked as expected.

Comment: Are you handling the query result in a client application? (eg Python or JavaScript code)

Comment: @BrunoPeres yes, i'm using java but if i change the name from `node` to `n` then i receive `{n = {a:1...}}` so it must come from neo4j

Answer (score 0):

(Update:) the solution in your question seems to be working fine.

```
match (node)
return distinct node { .*, type: labels(node) }
limit 1
```

Originally, I was suggesting to use the [`properties`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-properties) function, but that overcomplicates things unnecessarily:

```
match (node)
with node, properties(node) as props
return distinct props { .*, type: labels(node) }
limit 1
```

Comment: this way i get the same but instead of `node` i got `props`

Comment: What happens if you add an alias, i.e. `return distinct props { .*, type: labels(node) } AS x`

Comment: `[{x={a:1...}), {x={a:3...}}]`